# Почему не открывается порт в CentOS 7

Tags: сервер, centos7

Вобщем вопрос в заголовке.
Я пробовал через iptables. Пробовал отключать iptables и firewall не помогает, как открыть порт?
Например 21, 80, 2343, и 25565?

Нужно для ftp, http, ну и для игрового сервера.

Comment: `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=25564/tcp --permanent`и `firewall-cmd --reload` пробовали?

Comment: Нет, сейчас попробую

Comment: Не открылся, жду помощи

Comment: Есть ещё странность, nmap не показывает открытые порты моего ip, хотя 22 открыт, не связано ли это стем что порты не открываются?

Comment: `netstat -tlpn` так показывает открытые порты?

Comment: Да...Показывает

Comment: Может сервер перезагрузить

Comment: Перезагружу, и попробую порт проверить

Comment: Не помогло, через netstat пишет что открыт, но он не работает

Comment: Вот что выводит netstat https://ibb.co/zmXZLPh
ссылка ведёт на хостинг картинок, со скриншотом

Comment: Я имел в ввиду порт не 25564 а 25565, ну это я так предупредил

Comment: У вас 25565 открыт для ipv6, это учтено при подключении на него?

Comment: Нет, а как сделать чтоб порт был не  ipv6 а в ipv4 открыт?